# Why phantom doesn't renders page correctly?

Tags: phantomjs, render

I'm trying to render `html` to `jpg` using phantomjs.

Phantom renders stack overflow site perfectly, but doesn't render my own html page (which shows pieChart, generated by js).

here is phantom script:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var system = require('system');
var page = webPage.create();


page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };
page.open(system.args[1], function start(status) {
  page.render('index.jpeg', {format: 'jpeg', quality: '100'});
  phantom.exit();
});
```

And here is output img:

[image]

How to fix rendering?

Comment: Add `page.onError` callback to check for errors. Also try postponing `page.render` for a second with setTimeout to give js time to do its work.

Comment: @Vaviloff youa re right! timeout helped! Make your comment as an answer to check it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart is probably not shown in the image because the screenshot is made immediately after page is opened. Try to postpone making a screenshot for a second like this:

```
page.open(system.args[1], function start(status) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    page.render('index.jpeg', {format: 'jpeg', quality: '100'});
    phantom.exit();
  }, 1000);
});
```